# MySQL - How well will it scale with multiple concurrent remote connections each throwing 100's of writes per second?

Tags: mysql, load, scaling

I'm running a small server with MySQL installed that will have 10 to 20 clients remotely connected to it (direct connection) flooding it with data. The data could be coming in at 200-300 writes per second. Possibly more/less.

I'm wondering how well MySQL can handle this. The 'server' is an off the shelf computer. Nothing special/enterprise.

I don't know whether I should write a small async server that will sit between MySQL and the clients to buffer the data. Every 1000 rows or so, it can dump the data into MySQL.

Is this necessary? Or can MySQL handle this load?

Comment: Maybe it's feasible to write a little test-app with multi-treading that will open multiple connections and deliver writes like those you expect?

Comment: I'll definately do that. I just wanted to hear some thoughts on what people thought would be wiser. I don't want me test-app to show positive results then, after a week of constant flooding, MySQL/the HDD/etc dies from the strain.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook makes extensive use of MySQL [at commit rates higher than yours](http://www.facebook.com/MySQLatFacebook), so it's certainly *possible*. I don't know the exact commit rate at which it stops being *easy*.